# Replace the first occurrence of MORE than one space with newline

Tags: regex, file, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace the FIRST place that has more than one space with newline.

For example:

```
123 yes      foo bar       #
```

Would become:

```
123 yes
foo bar       #
```

I have tried

```
sed 's/^\s+/\n/' old > new
```

with no luck. I am also open to any other programs in linux that would allow me to do this such as awk, perl, or bash.

Comment: You know, I gave an answer to your last question that did this.

Comment: @Wintermute this is the first occurrence of MULTIPLE white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to match the beginning of line with `^`. Remove it. And you need to escape the `+` character. Try this instead:

```
 sed 's/\s\s\+/\n/' old > new
 sed -r 's/\s\s+/\n/' old > new   # less escaping with extended regex syntax
```

You can also use `\{min,max\}` to define a more specific repetition.

```
 sed 's/\s\{2,\}/\n/' old > new
 sed -r 's/\s{2,}/\n/' old > new  # less escaping with extended regex syntax
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this creates a newline in the first occurrence of whitespace rather than the first occurrence of multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{sub(/  +/,RS)}1' file
123 yes
foo bar       #
```

Or this:

```
awk '{sub(/\s\s+/,RS)}1'
```

Or this:

```
awk '{sub(/[[:space:]][[:space:]]+/,RS)}1'
```